# Weaviate is not automatically creating a schema

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, weaviate

```
   `Map<String, Object> dataSchema = new HashMap<>();
    dataSchema.put("labelName", "Images");
    dataSchema.put("image", encodedString);
    Result<WeaviateObject> result = client.data().creator()
    .withClassName("Test")
    .withProperties(dataSchema)
    .run();

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
    System.out.println(result.getError());
    return;
    }
    System.out.println(result.getResult());
}`
```

**[ERROR] => WeaviateError(statusCode=422, messages=[WeaviateErrorMessage(message=invalid object: module 'img2vec-neural': imageFields not present, throwable=null)])**

If I post to a class which does not exist, it should create the class by it's own but every time it is giving me the above mentioned error.

It was suppose to create that class, vectorize and stored the image

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.